# No redraw of ImageView when calling setImageBitmap inside of a Picasso Target

Tags: java, android, picasso

I have a big problem with loading images from cache on the getView of my Listadapter.
For image-loading we are using Picasso, and there I build a construct for loading images from cache and if there are no available images, THEN the images should be load from an online-URI.

(Here is a method, which is called inside of my `getView` of my Adapter)

```
 @Override
protected void loadImages(final VehicleResultListItem inCurrentItem) {

    // Try to load async the images from local path

    Picasso.with(mContext)
           .load(new File(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null),
                          inCurrentItem.getVehicleId()))
           .placeholder(inCurrentItem.getServiceType().getPlaceholderId())
           .noFade()
           .into(new Target() {
               @Override
               public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap,
                                          final Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                   mThumbnailImgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
               }

               @Override
               public void onBitmapFailed(final Drawable errorDrawable) {
                   // If the local-path-loading fails, try to grab the images online.
                   Picasso.with(mContext)
                          .load(inCurrentItem.getImageURIs().get(0).getImageUriSizeM())
                          .placeholder(inCurrentItem.getServiceType().getPlaceholderId())
                          .into(new Target() {
                              @Override
                              public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap,
                                                         final Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                                  // On succesfully online-loading of the images, store and show them
                                  mThumbnailImgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                  saveToInternalSorage(bitmap, inCurrentItem);
                              }

                              @Override
                              public void onBitmapFailed(final Drawable errorDrawable) {
                                  // NO interaction
                              }

                              @Override
                              public void onPrepareLoad(final Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                                  // No interaction
                              }
                          });
               }

               @Override
               public void onPrepareLoad(final Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                   mThumbnailImgView.setImageDrawable(placeHolderDrawable);
               }
           });
}
```

The problem is, that the image is loading correctly, but the imageView is not updating after image is loaded. In the OnImageLoaded, I am not in the UI-Thread, so ofc it does not update the view. So i tried anything:

- Runnable
- AsyncTask
- Androids solution from (http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html#concurrency)

It looks like the Threads are getting confused or something like that.

Maybe there is a problem in calling Picasso inside of a Picasso-Target?

Do u have any suggestion?

Greetz and thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Target` must not be an anonymous class. `Picasso` keeps a WeakReference on `Target` that will most likely get gc'ed by the time the request completes.

Javadoc clearly states that.

Make your `View` implement `Target` instead and use that as the target or keep a reference to your target instances.

Also `Picasso` handles disk caching for you automatically, unless you've shipped the assets with your app, I would recommend you simply download them and then let `Picasso` manage the disk/memory cache for you.